# call two ajax function inside each other

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have an ajax call and it works good , when i call a new ajax call inside the old one , i got error in the first call

## just one ajax call

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getRelatedConceptsAndRelations/"+conceptName+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var concepts = data[0];
            var relations = data[1];
            for(var i = 0 ; i < concepts.length ; i++){
                var IOS = '';
                $("#ioAddRelatedConcepts").append('<p>\n\
                  connect to\n\
                  <span class="ioAddConcept">'+concepts[i]+'</span>\n\
                  with\n\
                  <span class="ioAddRelation">'+relations[i]+'</span>\n\
                  <select name ="concetedIOs[]" class="TypeSelector">\n\
                  '+IOS+'</select>\n\
                  <span class="errorMessage"></span>\n\
                  <a href="#" class="removeA" id="aioRemoveIO">remove</a>\n\
                </p>\n\
                  <p>');
            }
        });
```

## after adding this ajax call

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getRelatedConceptsAndRelations/"+conceptName+"/TRUE",function(data){
            var concepts = data[0];
            var relations = data[1];
            for(var i = 0 ; i < concepts.length ; i++){
                $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+concepts[i]+"/TRUE",function(data1){
                    var IOS = '';
                    $("#ioAddRelatedConcepts").append('<p>\n\
                  connect to\n\
                  <span class="ioAddConcept">'+concepts[i]+'</span>\n\
                  with\n\
                  <span class="ioAddRelation">'+relations[i]+'</span>\n\
                  <select name ="concetedIOs[]" class="TypeSelector">\n\
                  '+IOS+'</select>\n\
                  <span class="errorMessage"></span>\n\
                  <a href="#" class="removeA" id="aioRemoveIO">remove</a>\n\
                </p>\n\
                  <p>');
                });
            }
        });
```

after that , the concepts[i] and the relations[i] will be as undifined
**and the data1.length always null** 
and the this is the second php code for ajax

```
public function getIOsForConcept($conceptName, $AJAX) {
        if ($AJAX) {
            $results = $this->model->getIOsForConcept($conceptName);
            $IOs = array();
            $i = 0;
            while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
                $IOs[$i] = $row['name'];
                $i++;
            }
            return json_encode($IOs);
        }
    }
```

and i tried it and it works good

Comment: Probably **not** a good idea to make the calls in a `for` loop like that -- they return asynchronously, ie, the loop itself will (almost certainly) complete before any of them returns, which may complicate things.  If you want them to happen in sequence, you should nest one inside the other.

Comment: @goldilocks but for each value of the first loop i have to get the data from server , so i put ajax call into a loop , any way , why the concpetp[i] and relation[i] doesn't work after ading the seocnd ajax call

Comment: You're probably going to need to pass concept and relation into the second ajax call and return it to use it, that's the only way you can be sure you've got the right variable values. Also you're not using the return value from the second ajax call?

Comment: @Tim i am used the value form the second ajax call , but in my example i delete it , because it is hug

Comment: @Tim but in the second ajax call i need just to send the concpet , not the relation ,

Comment: when error do you get in the first call?

Comment: @Tim no error on the first call alone , but when i added the second call , then concept[i] and relation[i] will be as undifend values

Comment: Why aren't you using the `data1` parameter of the inner `.getJSON()` callback? Not much point in request data that you don't use...

Comment: @nnnnnn i am using it , but i didn't but it in my question , because it is hug

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `concepts[i]` and the `relations[i]` are undefined within the callback function of the inner `$.getJSON()` function is that `$.getJSON()` is *aysnchronous* which means that the entire for loop will have finished running before any of the callbacks occur on the inner `$.getJSON()` calls - so by the time these inner callbacks occur `i` is one higher than the maximum index of the `concepts` and `relations` arrays.

To get around this you can introduce an extra closure to keep the values from each iteration:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/Ontology/getRelatedConceptsAndRelations/"+conceptName+"/TRUE", function(data){
   var concepts = data[0];
   var relations = data[1];
   for(var i = 0 ; i < concepts.length ; i++){
      (function(currentConcept, currentRelation) {
         $.getJSON("http://localhost/Mar7ba/InformationObject/getIOsForConcept/"+currentConcept+"/TRUE" , function(data1){
            var IOS = '';
            $("#ioAddRelatedConcepts").append('<p>\n\
              connect to\n\
              <span class="ioAddConcept">'+ currentConcept +'</span>\n\
              with\n\
              <span class="ioAddRelation">'+ currentRelation +'</span>\n\
              <select name ="concetedIOs[]" class="TypeSelector">\n\
              '+IOS+'</select>\n\
              <span class="errorMessage"></span>\n\
              <a href="#" class="removeA" id="aioRemoveIO">remove</a>\n\
              </p>\n\
              <p>');
         });
      })(concepts[i], relations[i]);
   }
});
```

The anonymous function I've added inside the for loop will run once per iteration creating separate closures each with their own `currentConcept` and `currentRelation`.

EDIT: To make it really obvious what I've changed compared to your original code--

Add the following line as the first thing inside your existing `for` loop:

```
   (function(currentConcept, currentRelation) {
```

And then the following line as the last thing before your existing `for` loop's closing `}`:

```
    })(concepts[i], relations[i]);
```

And then everywhere inside the `for` loop where you did have `concepts[i]` and `relations[i]` change them to `currentConcept` and `currentRelation`.

Comment: yes man , thank you , u make me understant the problem good , but please ur code has a syntax error and i am not good in jquery and can't know where is the wrong , mabye an missng closing }

Comment: Sorry, I obviously couldn't test it without the rest of your code. I think the problem was an extra `});` which I've now removed. The only change to your code should be adding the line immediately after the `for`, the line immediately before the end `}` of the `for`, and the change to use the `currentConcept` and `currentRelation` variables in the middle of your `.append()`.

Comment: ok i will try , but you right this `for(var i = 0 ; i < concepts.length ; i++){
      (` , pleaes be sure , is the ( after { is right?

Comment: Yes, the anonymous function I've added needs to be in parentheses so that it is treated as a function expression and not a function statement. That's also why it ends with `})(concepts[i], relations[i])`. If you count all the parens and curly-braces the opening and closing ones should match up...

Comment: yes yes man , there is no error now , but still one thing that i have to see why the returnd data from the second call doesn't show

Comment: now i add this code to the second call `IOS +="<option>Select IO</option>";
                        for(var j=0;j<data1.length;j++){
                            IOS+="<option>"+data1[j]+"<option>";
                        }` , but data.length is null :)

Comment: I can't help you with problems processing the data from the inner ajax calls, because you don't show the content of the JSON that is being returned.

Comment: yes i know dear , but please check my json function on my question , as it is i have not resonse , but when i put echo `$IOs[$i]` , google chrome js console prints the good results as i expected but still data1.lenght = null , really strange for me , anyway if u r boring from dealing with a begginer

Comment: yesssssssssssssss it wooooooooooooooooooorks aallllllllllllll gooooooooooood , the wrong , in my JSON i put return instread of echo

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a loop variable ( `i` in your case) inside a callback function - it'll have whatever value it had when the loop terminated by the time your async callback function is invoked.

As you're already using jQuery, you might as well use `$.each()`:

```
$.getJSON(..., function(data) {

    var concepts = data[0];
    var relations = data[1];

    $.each(concepts, function(i, value) {

        // concepts[i] is OK to use now, and is also in "value"
        // relations[i] is OK to use too

        $.getJSON(..., function() {

            // you can still use them here, too!

        });
    });
});
```

which will ensure that `i` is correctly bound to the current iteration number each time.

Comment: +1. This code is neater than my answer which kept the original `for` loop. Using `$.each()` introduces the required closure and tidies up the `for` at the same time. (Though note, @LinCR, that it works for the same reason as mine.)

Comment: @LinCR if it isn't working then much more likely there's something wrong with the JSON output from the first query.

Comment: @Alnitak , i am not downvote , and i show u the JSON call , please check it